# set a default checked option if the countryCode is US

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set as a default checked value of `Fitting` when the `countryCode =='US'`,

My code:

```
export default function ProductOptionsDefault({
  name,
  values,
  countryCode,
}: Props) {
  const {setSelectedOption, selectedOptions} = useProductOptions();
  const handleChange = (optionName: string, optionValue: string) => {
    if (setSelectedOption) {
      setSelectedOption(optionName, optionValue);
    }
  };
  return (
    <fieldset key={name} className="mt-4">
      {/* Name */}
      <legend className="mb-3 text-sm font-medium text-dark">{name}</legend>

      <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center gap-2">
        {values.map((value) => {
          const checked = selectedOptions?.[name] === value;
          const id = `option-${name}-${value}`;
          return (
            <label key={id} htmlFor={id}>
              <input
                className="sr-only"
                type="radio"
                id={id}
                name={`option[${name}]`}
                value={value}
                checked={checked}
                onChange={() => handleChange(name, value)}
              />
              <OptionButton checked={checked} label={value} />
            </label>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  );
}
```

`countryCode` value is either `US` or `UK`,
`selectedOptions` value by default is `{Size: '14"', Fitting: 'UK'}` then it will be changed when I select other options (e.g when I clicked on Fitting US -> {Size: '14"', Fitting: 'US'})
I just want to set as a default checked value for the Fitting to US when the countryCode is US as well. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you create a running https://codesandbox.io/ demo? We don't know the data structure of props .

Comment: consider https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you should look into the `useProductOptions` hook, or post it here. The default option is not decided in the code you posted, it is somewhere in the hook which is used to populate the `selectedOption` variable.

If I take a wild guess, you could pass the `countryCode` into the `useProductOptions` like

`const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useProductOptions(countryCode)`

and do the distinction between default values for US and UK there.

Comment: https://shopify.github.io/hydrogen-v1/hooks/product-variant/useproductoptions
This is the hook I am currently using